# definir função de média com pandas

Tags: pandas, csv

Eu tenho um arquivo csv que mede a temperatura de todos os dias do ano e preciso calcular a média mensal. Eu criei um loop e ate que deu certo mas queria saber se tem como definir uma função pra que o programa não fique muito extenso, e também gostaria de saber como plotar um gráfico de curva que mostre as temperaturas medias mensais.

Meu código:

```
import pandas as pd

dados = pd.read_csv('DadosClimaticos2018Londrina.csv',sep=';')
total = 0
t = 0

for i in range(len(dados)):
    linha = dados.iloc[i]
    data = linha['Data']
    mes = data[3:5]
    temperatura = linha['Temperatura']
    
    if int(mes) == 1:   
        total1 = total + 1
        t1 = ( t + temperatura ) 
        tm1 = t1 / total1        

    if int(mes) == 2:  
        total2 = total + 1
        t2 = ( t + temperatura )
        tm2 = t2 / total2

    if int(mes) == 3:  
        total3 = total + 1
        t3 = ( t + temperatura )
        tm3 = t3 / total3
    if int(mes) == 4:  
        total4 = total + 1
        t4 = ( t + temperatura )
        tm4 = t4 / total4

    if int(mes) == 5:  
        total5 = total + 1
        t5 = ( t + temperatura )
        tm5 = t5 / total5 
        
    if int(mes) == 6:  
        total6 = total + 1
        t6 = ( t + temperatura )
        tm6 = t6 / total6

    if int(mes) == 7:  
        total7 = total + 1
        t7 = ( t + temperatura )
        tm7 = t7 / total7

    if int(mes) == 8:  
        total8 = total + 1
        t8 = ( t + temperatura )
        tm8 = t8 / total8
        
    if int(mes) == 9:  
        total9 = total + 1
        t9 = ( t + temperatura )
        tm9 = t9 / total9
        
    if int(mes) == 10:  
        total10 = total + 1
        t10 = ( t + temperatura )
        tm10 = t10 / total10
        
    if int(mes) == 11:  
        total11 = total + 1
        t11 = ( t + temperatura )
        tm11 = t11 / total11 
        
    if int(mes) == 12:  
        total12 = total + 1
        t12 = ( t + temperatura )
        tm12 = t12 / total12
```

Comment: Gigi, bom dia! Esse calculo pode ser feito utilizando funções que ja existem no pandas? Abraço!

Comment: ss, mas qual? é isso q eu n sei

Comment: Caso seja somente calcular a média, a resposta abaixo te atende. Coloquei o calculo dentro de uma função e ela retorna um dataframe com esses cálculos. Abraço!

Comment: obrigada, facilitou bastante o problema

Comment: Caso a resposta seja o que você procurava, considere em marcar como aceita. Isso ajuda as pessoas a visualizarem que a pergunta já foi resolvida e também estimula outras pessoas a responderem suas perguntas. [Veja como](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLkG.jpg). Abraço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importando o pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Lendo os dados e armazenando em uma variável
parse_dates converte a coluna Data em datetime64

```
dados = pd.read_csv('./DadosClimaticos2018Londrina.csv', sep = ';', parse_dates = ['Data'])
```

Criando a coluna mês

```
dados['Mes'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(dados['Data'], yearfirst = True).month
```

Função que retorna um data frame com a média das temperaturas por mês

```
def media_temperatura_mes(dataframe):
    return pd.DataFrame(dataframe.groupby('Mes')['Temperatura'].mean()).reset_index()
```

Chamando a função e armazenando o resultado em uma variável

```
temperaturas = media_temperatura_mes(dados)
```

Imprimindo

```
temperaturas

   Mes  Temperatura
0   1   24.763441
1   2   23.852381
2   3   24.776344
3   4   24.008889
4   5   21.458065
5   6   22.020000
6   7   22.750538
7   8   21.627957
8   9   23.108889
9   10  23.232258
10  11  24.653333
11  12  26.073118
```

---

Exemplo para plotar o gráfico

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(temperaturas['Mes'], temperaturas['Temperatura']) #define o que será plotado
plt.ylim(15) #define o limite mínimo do eixo y
plt.xticks(range(1,len(temperaturas['Mes']) + 1)) #adiciona de 1 até 12 ao eixo x
plt.xlabel('Mês') #adiciona label ao eixo x
plt.ylabel('Temperatura Média') #adiciona label ao eixo y
plt.show() # mostra o gráfico
```