# Função para calculo da media mensal

Tags: python, funções

Quero calcular a media de temperatura de cada mês do ano utilizando uma função. Não esta dando certo. Segue o código que tentei

```
import pandas as pd

tabela = pd.read_csv('DadosClimaticos2018Londrina.csv', sep =';')
tabela['Mes'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(tabela['Data'], yearfirst = True).month
tabela.to_csv('novo.csv',sep = ';', index = False)
    
def mediatemp(soma):
    soma = 0
    quant = 0
    for i in range(len(tabela)):
        linha= tabela.iloc[i]
        temp = linha['Temperatura']
        soma = soma + temp
        quant = quant + 1
        media = temp/quant
    return media

print(mediatemp)
```

Comment: [Veja se isso resolve o que você quer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/481895/definir-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-m%c3%a9dia-com-pandas)

Comment: Sem saber como estão os dados na sua planilha é difícil. Mas você já experimentou usar o `df.mean()`? É uma função nativa do Pandas para calcular a média

Comment: Outra coisa: Você parece estar dividndo a coluna bruta de temperatura pela quantidade de dias. Precisa fazer um somatório da coluna de temperatura primeiro.

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que o código da obtenção dos dados está correto, a função da média deveria ser algo deste género

```
def mediatemp(tabela):
    soma = 0
    for i in range(len(tabela)):
        linha= tabela.iloc[i]
        temp = linha['Temperatura']
        soma += temp
    return soma / (i+1)
```

Acho que devia rever os conceitos de uma linguagem orientada a objetos.
Não percebi o argumento `soma` pedido pela função. A mesma função é chamada sem `()` nem argumentos. Por fim, a sua variável `soma` não estava a ser utilizada no calculo da `media`, que no código que apresentou apenas iria retornar o valor que calculou no ultimo ciclo.

Apesar do código que apresentei, existem muitas outras soluções para esse propósito, muitas delas provavelmente até melhores.